# How to display the line number in a mui textfield component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have to do a little code editor online so I need to display in front of each line the number of the line.

Is it possible with the mui textfield's component ?

I've tried with a  which is changing with the number of line of the text fields but they are not aligned and they don't fit

For now my code look like this :

```
import { Box, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { MainBox, TextArea } from "./styles";

function useLineText(nbLines = 1): [any, any] {
    const [newLine, setNewLine] = useState('1\n')

    const updateNewLine = function() {
        let myLine = '1\n'
        for(let count = 1; count < nbLines; count++) {
            myLine = myLine + `${count + 1}\n`
            //console.log(myLine)
        }
        setNewLine(myLine)
    }
    

    return [newLine, updateNewLine]
}


const CodeInputField = () => {
    const [nbLines, setNbLines] = useState(1)
    const [CountLineText, setCountLineText] = useLineText(nbLines)

    function replaceWithBr() {
        return CountLineText.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
      }

    function useHandleTyping(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        //console.log(event.target.value.toString().split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length)
        setNbLines(event.target.value.toString().split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length)
        setCountLineText(nbLines)
        //console.log(CountLineText)
    }
      
    return(
        <Box sx={MainBox}>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: replaceWithBr()}}/>
            <TextField sx={TextArea} multiline rows={8} onChange={useHandleTyping} id="outlined-multiline-static" />
        </Box>
    )
}

export default CodeInputField
```

and for the style :

```
export const MainBox = () => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    border: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    width: 'fit-content',
    maxHeight: 1/2,
    fontSize: 17.5
})

export const TextArea = () => ({
    borderLeft: 1,
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
        border: 'none',
        borderRadius: 0
    }
})
```

thank for the help

Comment: I think you are trying to stretch a textfield beyond its limits with your goals and also its reinventing the wheel a little bit. Why not use codemirror? https://uiwjs.github.io/react-codemirror/

Comment: You're right, I'm going to look on this side instead.
Thank you